# Are cherry-pickers a new thing in spaceflight?

Tags: launch, launch-site, equipment

NASA Spaceflight's [Chang Zheng-4B launches with two Tianhui 2 satellites](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2021/08/tianhui-2-group-2/) links to the following @Cosmic_Penguin [tweet](https://twitter.com/Cosmic_Penguin/status/1428136680473587715)

> It turns out to be...something else, an LM-4B successfully launching the 2nd pair of Tianhui-2 cartography satellites at 22:32 UTC

which includes the image below of two technicians doing something to the side of a rocket while standing on a "cherry picker" or [Aerial work platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_work_platform)

The NASA Spaceflight video *Ship 20 Stacked on top of Super Heavy Booster 4 for the First Time | SpaceX Boca Chica* linked below (starting at `02:45`) shows a bunch of really tall ones going up and down as well.

**Question:** Are cherry-pickers a new thing in spaceflight? Until these two recent incidences I've never noticed their use, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything. Are their use on rockets associated with their launching before, <s>during</s> or after a rescheduled attempt somewhat common, or rare?

[image: It turns out to be...something else, an LM-4B successfully launching the 2nd pair of Tianhui-2 cartography satellites at 22:32 UTC. https://twitter.com/Cosmic_Penguin/status/1428136680473587715]

Comment: [Do we need both equipment and ground-equipment tags?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2852/12102)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cherry pickers go back to at least 1961.

[image: Mercury Redstone]

Mercury-Redstone 3 (MR-3) flight configuration with cherry picker, on one of many tests conducted to evaluate astronaut escape feasibility.
Image # : 71P-0257

I recall other photos of Alan Shephard's rocket with a cherry picker nearby, but I could not locate those photos immediately.

Photo from [Nasa Commons on Flicker](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasacommons/9460616276/in/photolist-fpfFPd-fq18BJ).

Answer (score 8):

The Shuttle Mission Simulator's Motion Base Simulator was equipped with a cherry picker.

Purpose: rescue the crew if the motion system got stuck in a weird position.

The cherry picker can be seen behind the simulator in the 2nd picture in this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38755/6944